# How to receive bluetooth LE signals without "time outs/gaps" on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, rssi

We are building an app which needs to connect to a peripheral BLE device. This device is not continuously broadcasting but just if a switch is activated.

For iOS we can connect very fast, no matter if the switch or the app is activated first.

For Android it works not as fast as iOS, but still fast if the switch is activated before the app is activated. One way round, if the app is activated and 5/6 seconds later the switch is activated, we can not detect any signal for about 25 seconds.

After some extra testing, we noticed that we can discover BLE signals for about 5/6 seconds and than have a "timeout" of 25 seconds all the time on multiple Android devices.

We tried an "infinity scan" and also tried a "periodic scan" with 6 seconds scan time and 500ms scan timeout. We are using "SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY" but unfortunately all without any result.

We know that the BLE stack of Android is not very reliable/stable all the time so we also tried other libraries (which probably also use Android library in background i think) also without any result.

My question is if this is a known "problem" of BLE on Android as we do not have this problem on iOS so it can not be the peripheral device? Or is there a way to speed up connection on Android if the switch is activated 5/6 seconds before the app is opened? (so fix the signal gap)

I cant find questions or information about this/similar problems on stack overflow or Google... Or is this probably a wrong parameter setting in our software?

Hope someone can help me/us as we are struggling with this for a while...

Comment: Do you want to connect to the device or just receive advertisements?

Comment: In first place just receive the advertisements. If the device is found where we are looking for, we want connect with it. within the 25 seconds "time out" we don't receive any advertisement so this is actually the main problem.

Comment: What's your advertising interval?